# Upgrading from createContainer to withTracker with React Router V4

Tags: meteor

I upgraded meteor and I started receiving deprecation warning for createContainer(). As a result, I've tried to implement `withTracker` however now I'm getting `Component(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`. I'm not sure what I'm missing here, can someone point out my error.

Path: `App.jsx`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

// IsCandidate Spefic Routes
import TestContainer from '../../containers/candidate/TestContainer';

const App = appProps => (
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <div className="bgColor">
        <NavBar {...appProps} />
        <Grid className="main-page-container">
          <Switch>
            {/* candidate routes */}
            <IsCandidate exact path="/candidate/testpage/:id" component={withTracker(TestContainer)} {...appProps} />

            {/* IsPublic routes */}
            <Route render={function () {
              return <p>Page not found</p>;
            }}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>
);

App.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  isCandidate: PropTypes.bool
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  const loggingIn = Meteor.loggingIn();
  return {
    loggingIn,
    isCandidate: !loggingIn && !!Meteor.userId() && !!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'isCandidate'),
  };
}, App);
```

Path: `IsCandidate.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const IsCandidate = ({ loggingIn, isCandidate, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if (loggingIn) return <div />;
      return isCandidate ?
      (<Component loggingIn={loggingIn} isCandidate={isCandidate} {...rest} {...props} />) :
      (<Redirect to="/login" />);
    }}
  />
);

IsCandidate.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  isCandidate: PropTypes.bool,
  component: PropTypes.func
};

export default IsCandidate;
```

Path: `Testcontainer.jsx`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Test } from '../../../api/test/test';

import TestPage from '../../pages/candidate/TestPage';

export default TestContainer = withTracker(({ match }) => {

  const testHandle = Meteor.subscribe('test', match.params.id);
  const loadingTest = !testHandle.ready();
  const testCollection = Test.findOne(match.params.id);
  const testExist = !loadingTest && !!testCollection;


return {
  loadingTest,
  testExist,
  testCollection: testExist ? testCollection : {}
};

}, TestPage);
```

**Update**

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  const loggingIn = Meteor.loggingIn();
  return {
    loggingIn,
    isCandidate: !loggingIn && !!Meteor.userId() && !!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'isCandidate'),
    isEmployer: !loggingIn && !!Meteor.userId() && !!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'isEmployer'),
    isAdmin: !loggingIn && !!Meteor.userId() && !!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'isAdmin')
  };
})(App);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `App.jsx` you import withTracker but use `createContainer`.

`withTracker` takes only one argument (your reactive function) and wraps your child component where `createContainer` took 2 arguments (function and component).

```
createContainer(fn, C);

withTracker(fn)(C);
```

**EDIT**
Remove the `withTracker` call in App.js from this line:

```
<IsCandidate exact path="/candidate/testpage/:id" component={withTracker(TestContainer)} {...appProps} />
```

so it becomes

```
<IsCandidate exact path="/candidate/testpage/:id" component={TestContainer} {...appProps} />
```

How about it?

Comment: when I change `export default createContainer(() => {` to `export default withTracker(() => {` I still get `Component(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned`

Comment: Read my answer carefully and change not only the import but also the implementation of the container. You cannot simply swap `createContainer` with `withTracker`.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, I appreciate it, however, I'm still stumped by this. I've made an update (see above) but I'm not following what I'm missing. I've read the meteor docs a bunch of times and as far as I can tell I'm doing it the way they suggest. Could you please show me what I'm missing here. I'm still a noob when it comes to code.

Comment: Updated my answer. Note that you are also still using `createContainer` in App.js w/o importing it.